# Why does the following time sorting code break for devices using a 24-hour clock?

Tags: swift

Apologies if this is an obvious question, but I built an app with Swift a while back and periodically make updates to it, but each time I come back to it I'm pretty rusty.

I have the following code that sorts items by time:

```
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

items = items.sorted(by: {dateFormat.date(from: $0.time)! < dateFormat.date(from: $1.time)!})
```

This works fine for devices using 12-hour time, but throws an error for devices using 24-hour time (and possibly if the locale uses 12-hour time, but not AM/PM?).

Through reading various Stack Overflow questions and developer documentation, and from some trial and error, I've found that adding the following line of code fixes the issue:

```
dateFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

If I'm sorting by time and I've specified my date format, why does it matter what locale a device is using? When the [DateFormatter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) says:

> ... provides a representation of a specified date that is appropriate
>   for a given locale.

Does that mean every date formatter must have a locale specified and since I hadn't specified one in my original code it assumed the locale of the device? Therefore, if a user was using a locale that didn't support a 12-hour clock it threw an error?

Comment: Set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Based on [nsdateformatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com), `h` represents the time for a 12 hour clock, where `H` represents the time for a 24 hour clock

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rmaddy! From googling I found "en_US_POSIX ... a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences." - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried changing the format to use HH, but it still threw an error when trying to sort on a device using a 24-hour clock.

Comment: @Ryan What's the error?  The "obviously stupid" question, what are you inputs?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the error I get is "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and the inputs are time representations in string data types (e.g. 1:00 PM, 4:00 PM, etc.)

Comment: @Ryan As I see it (and I'm blind ), you're going to need two formatters, one for 12 hour time and one for 24 hour time, `h:mm a` and `H:mm`, you're going to have to try and parse your input through both of these and take the non-nil result (otherwise it would be a invalid input)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I had tried that, but I tried it again just to be sure. I added logic to detect if the device was using a 24-hour or 12-hour clock and used "H:mm" and "h:mm a", respectively. I stepped through the code and verified the 24-hour format was used when appropriate, but unfortunately it still resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An approach...

Since you have two possible formats, you need two formatters...

```
let format12 = DateFormatter()
format12.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
// Fix the possible formatting and avoid issues with the local and parsing
format12.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let format24 = DateFormatter()
format24.dateFormat = "H:mm"
format24.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Now you need to parse your input into date values...

```
var items: [String] = ["1:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "13:00", "16:00"]

var dates: [Date?] = items.map {
    if let value = format24.date(from: $0) { return value }
    else if let value = format12.date(from: $0) { return value }
    return nil
}
```

And sort it...

```
dates.sort {
    guard let lhs = $0, let rhs = $1 else { return true }
    return lhs < rhs
}
```

Now, the above anticipates that some values may be `nil` and takes appropriate action.

Now you could, instead, use `compactMap` to remove the possible `nil` values, for example...

```
var dates: [Date] = items.compactMap {
    if let value = format24.date(from: $0) { return value }
    else if let value = format12.date(from: $0) { return value }
    return nil
}

dates.sort {
    guard let lhs = $0, let rhs = $1 else { return true }
    return lhs < rhs
}

dates.sort { $0 < $1 }
```

I dumped all of this into Playground and have no issues

## Side note...

If you are getting `nil` values with either of the two formatters, then you need to take a closer look at the values and determine how they are not fitting the pattern of the formatters and take appropriate actions to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create Date object and sort 
you can create timestamp and then sort it based on timestamp.